# Reacte Native Flashlist медленная загрузка или задержка загрузки данных

Tags: react-native

Использую Flashlist в React Native. Проблема в том что при открытии страницы Flashlist загружает первые три элемента,

[image: пример в начале]

потом через 5 секунд все.

[image: пример после]

Массив большой. После загрузки все работает нормально и быстро. Примерную высоту элемента знаю и передаю в Flashlist estimateditemsize и в контейнер. Хотел бы узнать это нормально и нужно просто ограничить длину массива (примерно 200) или есть другой вариант.

```
           <View style={{ minHeight: 100 }}>
            <FlashList
              ListEmptyComponent={<Text>Not found</Text>}
              data={flowList}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                if (typeof item === "string") {
                  return (<Text style={styles.alphabetContainer}>{item}</Text>)
                } else {
                  return (
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.flow_name}</Text>
                    </View>
                  )
                }
              }}
              getItemType={(item) => {
                return typeof item === "string" ? "sectionHeader" : "row";
              }}
              estimatedItemSize={30}
            />
          </View>
```